# basic client server: Passing strings properly

Tags: string, utf-8, python-3.x, client-server

I am making a simple client/server that will pass strings back and forth. It is only slightly more advanced than an echo server. However, I am having some issue with passing the strings. I first ran into an issue where I was using the incorrect data type (not converting to utf-8), but am still having an issue.

Here is my server code:

```
import socket
import re 

host     = ''
port     = 15008
backlog  = 5 
size     = 1024
QUIT     = bytes("QUIT"    , "utf-8")
BYE      = bytes("BYE"     , "utf-8")
MATCH    = bytes("MATCH"   , "utf-8")
NO_MATCH = bytes("NO MATCH", "utf-8")

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.bind((host,port)) 
s.listen(backlog)

while 1: 
    client, address = s.accept() 

    regex = client.recv(size)
    if regex == QUIT:
        client.send(BYE)
        client.close()
        break

    string = client.recv(size)
    if string == QUIT:
        client.send(BYE)
        client.close()
        break

    if re.match(regex, string):
        client.send(MATCH)
    else:
        client.send(NO_MATCH)
```

and the client code:

```
import socket 

host = 'localhost' 
port = 15008
size = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.connect((host,port))

s.send(bytes('[ws]', "utf-8"))
s.send(bytes('s', "utf-8")) 
data = s.recv(size) 
print('Should match: ' + data)

s.close()
```

Right now both the server and client just get hung-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to use decode.

```
data = s.recv(size).decode("utf-8")
```